# d3: Path data generator and if-statement

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have two different `d3.svg.area()` variables in my code, where each one for itself basically works fine (elements are drawn on the SVG as I expect it).

Now I wanted to change my code in order to select one of the two methods, dependent on a condition - and it's not working at all, nothing is drawn on the screen, but the console also logs no errors.

My code looks like this:

```
    var lineFunction = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function (d) {return d.x;})
        .y(function (d) {return d.y;})
        .y0(function (d) {return (d.y+ 10) ;})
        .y1(function (d) {return (d.y- 10) ;})
        .interpolate("basis");

    var otherFunction = d3.svg.area()
        ....//analogue to above one


    d3arrows.enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", function (d){
                if(condition == 1) {lineFunction}
                else {otherFunction}
             ;})
             //.attr("d", lineFunction ) <--like this it works!
            .attr("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("stroke-width",  2)
            .attr("fill",  "yellow");
```

I also tried to use `return lineFunction` and `return otherFunction`, but this is causing an "Invalid value for  attribute error" in the d3 library itself.

The structure of the if-statement should be correct, it's taken from answers to former posts in StackOverflow. But none of them is using a path data generator, so maybe that's the problem with my code.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two errors:

1. You are missing a `return` in your callback.
2. You are not passing parameters to the line generator functions.

One way around this could be like this:

```
d3arrows.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", function (d) {
            if (condition == 1) {
                return lineFunction(d);
            } else {
                return otherFunction(d);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Perfect answer, passing the parameters in combination with the return statement made it work. Great!

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing elements to the functions.

Try :

```
.attr("d", function (d){
                if(condition == 1) {lineFunction(d)}
                else {otherFunction(d)}
             ;})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d3arrows.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", function (d){
            if(condition == 1) {
                return lineFunction(d);
            } else {
                return otherFunction(d);
            }
         ;})
         //.attr("d", lineFunction ) <--like this it works!
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width",  2)
        .attr("fill",  "yellow");
```

`lineFunction` and `otherFunction` need to be explicitly called. d3 will automatically do this for you when sending a function into `attr` but if you want to use them elsewhere you have to call them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was wondering why I need it in one case and in the other I don't - now it is clear. Though, I also had to add a return statement to make it work.